# In visual basic 6.0 using crystal report 8.5, how can i mail the report directly?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I am using visual basic 6.0 and crystal report 8.0

how can I mail the report generated directly to any mail id?

Answer (score 0):

This is for SMTP. See the docs for using Exchange.

```
Set emailObj      = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
emailObj.From     = "fred@gmail.com"

emailObj.To       = "fred@gmail.com"

emailObj.Subject  = "Test CDO"
emailObj.TextBody = "Test CDO"

emailObj.AddAttachment "c:\windows\win.ini"

Set emailConfig = emailObj.Configuration

emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")    = 2  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1  
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl")      = true 
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")    = "fred"
emailConfig.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")    = "pass"
emailConfig.Fields.Update

emailObj.Send

If err.number = 0 then Msgbox "Done"
```

Comment: Doesn't CDO require a separate installation? Doesn't it also require Exchange to be installed?

Comment: No it doesn't require exchange, it has two modes smtp and exchange. It is installed in many client systems such as Vista.

Comment: Older CDOs required MAPI. There is CDO for Windows 2000 (internet based) and CDO version 1.2.1 is mapi based (and a related CDO for NTS for IIS/Exchange). Dim objSession As MAPI.Session and Dim objSession As CDONTS.Session